# Similar to Excel's line charts?

Tags: pstricks, plot, excel

How could I create charts as the follow ones, which were produced by Microsoft Excel?
[image: basic National Accounting Identities]
[image: consumer loan]
[image: table with numbers for the charts]

Comment: take a look at the excellent [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) package

Comment: Can you simply copy/paste a small amount of data here so that we can demonstrate different options?

Comment: @percusse Indicator Name 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998
GDP per capita, PPP (constant 2005 international $) 1.732.502.852 1.768.900.924 1.761.774.062 1.717.739.533 1.737.565.752 1.760.478.791 1.789.413.624 1.842.918.632 1.894.645.346
GNI per capita, PPP (constant 2005 international $) 1.768.116.213 1.812.780.422 1.810.912.926 1.760.435.709 1.781.786.117 180.583.803 1.829.719.306 1.885.167.049 193.721.716

Comment: @giannis Please add this info to your question by editing such that the structure is kept. Otherwise it's a pain to copy paste that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know how to copy paste from an image but here is an example by transposing your comment back in Excel.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{eurosym}      %<-- For EURO symbol 
\usepackage{filecontents} %<-- To create the data file on the go

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
in gdp gni
1990  1732502852  1768116213
1991  1768900924  1812780422
1992  1761774062  1810912926
1993  1717739533  1760435709
1994  1737565752  1781786117
1995  1760478791   180583803
1996  1789413624  1829719306
1997  1842918632  1885167049
1998  1894645346   193721716
\end{filecontents*}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    width=0.9\textwidth,
    height=4cm,
    ymajorgrids,
    title = {Greece: GDP \& GNI (2005 data)},
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ytick scale label code/.code={$\times$bn\EUR{}},
    legend pos=outer north east
    ]
        \addplot table[x=in,y=gdp] {data.csv};\addlegendentry{GDP}
        \addplot table[x=in,y=gni] {data.csv};\addlegendentry{GNI}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I've used the `.csv` extension but it's actually not so better use `.txt` or `.dat` to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 4):

You can use several packages, that help creating diagrams. The basic packages, that can be used on a high level are [pstricks](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks) and [pgf/tikz](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf). They are primarly designed for .ps and .pdf output respectively, but can also be used for other output formats. Both packages are base for even higher level packages designed for plotting graphs: [pst-plot](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-plot) and [pgfplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots).

You can use either the base package or the higher level packages to achieve these diagrams. So look at the documentation of either one and decide, which one to use.

Comment: I find it really difficult, because -for example- I don't know how to create a .data file so as to have available all the data for the chart.

Comment: If you have the data ready in an excel file, you can save this excel file as comma separated value file (.csv, .data, .whatever). Both packages can work with this format. Maybe, you have to adjust some options, because comma separated value isn't a totally fixed format.